# What is the difference between Google Webmaster Tools and Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console

I see many questions concerning the Google Search Console and Google Webmaster Tools.  What is the major differences between the two services and which one should I be using for my Website?  Is it possible to just use one or do I need to use both services to submit a sitemap?

Comment: Google Webmaster Central Blog reporting the change in branding: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/05/announcing-google-search-console-new.html

Comment: The latter is a rebranding of the former. No difference...

Answer (score 5):

What is the major differences between the two services?

None. Nada. Zip. Bupkis.

They are precisely the same thing. Webmaster tools was renamed Search Console.

Thanks to @w3dk - He was able to find the original announcement here:

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/05/announcing-google-search-console-new.html

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen it looks like Google Webmasters is converting to Google Search Console. I have had google webmasters bookmarked since inception and once I signed up for google search console my webmaster bookmark redirects to search console.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same service. The service is called search console and is also referred to as webmaster tools. You have "webmasters/tools" in the URL and "search console" as the title of the page.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en